# Why is WinMerge ignoring one line but not the other?

Tags: regex, winmerge

I'm comparing two different files, and am using these line filters:

- `^'` - Ignore lines which start with a `'` character
- `^[ |\t]*//` - Ignore lines which start zero or more spaces or tabs, proceeded by `//`
- `[\/\/]+.*` - Ignore lines with `//` proceeded by any number of characters, with the only restriction being line breaks.

However, the ignore behavior seems to be inconsistent:

[image]

Why is that first case statement ignored but the second one is not?

I'm guessing it has something to do with the `/` in the string being assigned, but my third line filter explicitly looks for 2 `//` so that *shouldn't* be the problem...

Comment: Are you sure that `[\/\/]+.*` does what you think it does?

Comment: `[\/\/]+.*` matches a / to the end of the line. [] is "anything in this group", and you are just listing the / character twice. So it does not need a second / to make a match. It is equivalent to `\/.*`

Comment: @sab669 `(\/\/)+.*` would match `//` to end of line (.* makes + redundant). But that is probably what you wanted. (the `()`, not the redundancy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[\/\/]+.*` matches a / to the end of the line. [] is "anything in this group", and you are just listing the / character twice. So it does not need a second / to make a match. It is equivalent to `\/.*`

`(\/\/)+.*` would match // to end of line (.* makes + redundant). But that is probably what you wanted. (the (), not the redundancy) It is equivalent to `\/\/.*`

Comment: @sab669 Wrapped comment explanations into answer. :3